# Alternative to sending comma separated parameter by querystring

Tags: url, query-string, web

I am trying to send querystring parameter as below but i think that using comma in querystring is not valid so what is better alternative to comma separator for path parameter?

```
<a href="/?path=1,2,3"></a>
```

I don't want to send like `<a href="/?path=1&path=2&path=3"></a>` which can be quite long.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `%2C`, wich is the url-encoded value of `,`.

Comment: Allready ASP.NET MVC Framework translate to url encoded value but i feel that it is not seo friendly or not better way. That is why i didnt want to use. Is there any downside of url encoded values ?

Comment: The HTTP protocols takes care of decoding the urls, so in your program the param `p` would be `1,2,3`, however, the user would see the url encoded in their browser, which you might now want, so I guess you could use `-` as the delimiter, since it doesn't need to bee encoded.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be SEO friendly. It's in the query string anyway.

Answer (score 10):

The comma is allowed, also in its un-encoded form, as it is a reserved character.

Have a look at this RFC section: [RFC 3986 - 2.2.  Reserved Characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2)

As I understad this, it just depends on how your server handles URLs that contain a comma. Give it a try and find out.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the escaped (or percent-encoded if we're being pedantic) value of ',', or an unreserved character as per [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.3) (- _ . ~).

Answer (score 0):

You can send it simply, i use lodash to collect select product id

```
 vm.saleStartDate = vm.saleDateRange.startDate.toISOString();
 vm.saleEndDate = vm.saleDateRange.endDate.toISOString();

 vm.productIds = _.map(vm.selectedProducts, 'id').join(',');

 vm.iFrameURL = host + '/Reports/MonthWiseAvgSalesViewer.aspx?id=MonthWiseAvgSalesReport.rdlc&salesSD=' + vm.saleStartDate + '&salesED=' + vm.saleEndDate +
               '&prIds=' + vm.productIds
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending integers, use spaces as a separator.

Answer (score -3):

You could use pipes "|" as a delimiter, but you're going to have to process it on the server side. Not sure it's worth the hassle though.

Comment: Pipes are not valid in URLs at all, per official specs.