# How can I retrieve multiple query parameter values with Django?

Tags: python, django, query-string

My url has `http://127.0.0.1:8000/theme/category/?q=check,hello`, How to retrive values of query parameter

When I try doing `query = request.GET.get('q')` I only get the `check` but `hello` is missing.

Any help in getting both check and hello from query string will be helpful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle request.GET with multiple variables for the same parameter in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910165/how-to-handle-request-get-with-multiple-variables-for-the-same-parameter-in-djan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use %2C, wich is the url-encoded value of `,`.

source : [Alternative to sending comma separated parameter by querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359352/alternative-to-sending-comma-seperated-parameter-by-querystring)

Answer (score 14):

For the URL `http://example.com/blah/?myvar=123&myvar=567` you can use [`getlist()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) like this:

```
request.GET.getlist('myvar')
```